# Dashboard - Run as Logged in user Limitations

Tags: dashboard

I work more with reports and dashboards.

- I am given a scenario that has 4 Management units and several countries under those. Eg. Management unit North Cone Group would have countries (America, Columbia,Peru,Mexico etc) , Management unit South Cone Group will have (Argentina, Bolivia, Uruguay etc). Likewise i have 3 more management units and several other countries.
- I am given a set of **users(40 users)**. Also I am given a permutation-combination User Access chart that says set of 10 users will have access to all management unit (includes all countries in that- kind of admins). Another set will have access to only North Cone Group. One set will have access to only south cone group. One set will have access to north cone group and 2 countries under that(i.e say Argentina, Uruguay)
- Likewise working on these permutation-combination i could figure out **14 such groups with management unit-country combination**.
- According to my understanding , If i create groups then , 14 such groups and sharing rule will be created for these groups
- My biggest challenge here is i **have approx 80 Dashboards in my org**. If I create a sharing rule, that would not apply to a dashboard. Any user logging in would see report data according to the access given to him/her. But as far as dashboards are concerned these rules don't apply. When i click on any of the dashboard and set it to run as logged in user that works fine. But again there is a limitation. I am given to understand that i can apply this to **max 3 dashboards.**
- An alternative suggested was. I create dashboard folders according to groups. i.e if i have **14 groups** then create **14 dashboard folders**.
  Clone an existing dashboard 14 times. and the unique name will vary according to the folder that it is placed. So here if i have 80 such dashboards then 1120 clones will have to be made (very tedious).
  Please suggest me a good option to go about solving this task.**strong text**

Comment: please use some text formatting in your question. It's not very appealing to start read the question in this format.

Comment: Please share some valuable inputs

Comment: Register your upvote - https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IRSu

Alternative solutions to fix, refer the salesforce article - 
Find the dynamic dashboards in my organization - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326117&type=1&mode=1 (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326117&type=1&mode=1)